# Efficiently handling multiple For Loops and If Statements in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with two dataframes. One containing the pair of unique keys and the other having values of those unique keys. There are almost 5.8million pairs.

Dataframe 1 - `pair_df`

| key1 | key2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| a | c |
| b | c |
| e | f |

Dataframe 2 - `key_value_df`

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 432 |
| b | 654 |
| c | 874 |
| e | 014 |
| f | 421 |

I want a dataframe in such a way that in the dataframe 1, the respective values for both keys are present as additional columns.

Required Dataframe

| key1 | key2 | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 432 | 654 |
| a | c | 432 | 874 |
| b | c | 654 | 874 |
| e | f | 014 | 421 |

I tried with the following code:

```
def find_vect(key_value_df, pair_df, key_name, vect_name):
    pair_df[vect_name]=''
    count=0
    for idx1, pic1 in enumerate(pair_df[key_name]):  # key_name='key1
        for idx2, pic2 in enumerate(key_value_df['key']):
            if pic1==pic2:
                vect = list(key_value_df.iloc[idx2, 0:49])
                pair_df.loc[idx1, vect_name] = vect
                count+=1
                if count%10000==0:
                    print(count)
```

This is a simplified version of the actual code and might contain some error.
The logic is working but due to huge number of data, it is taking a lot of time for the process.
Also same code has to be rerun for the other key in dataframe 1. This is making the process very time consuming.

Is there any other efficient way to solve the problem?

Comment: There are ready to use operations like [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) or `df.join`. Don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created from `key_value_df` by set `key` to `index`:

```
s = key_value_df.set_index('key')['value']

pair_df['value1'] = pair_df['key1'].map(s)
pair_df['value2'] = pair_df['key2'].map(s)
```

Comment: Hello @Jezrael, at first it seams that the solution works but actually it is creating list of list for the value. It is creating nested lists of same value.

Comment: @RajRajeshwariPrasad - So input data looks different like in question?

Comment: Hello @Jezrael, I reworked on the solution you provided and found that the problem was in the input. The input itself was a nested list. I figured out the problem and now the your solution works absolutely fine. Thanks a lot.